# Paste JSON file in SQLITE3 table

Tags: php, sqlite

Does anybody know is there any php library to paste json file in sqlite3 table  or php associative array? Is this possible at all ? I have JSON file or associative array with identifiers like column names and I don't want to iterate through JSON , I would like to in one step paste values from json in table. Can somebody help with associative array or json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your json to XML and import to table(Using SQlite manager) if you want to import manually.

Otherwise, if you want to use php, You can explore about xml to db import options